# ImageView src with drawable selector ignores enabled state

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

When using a state selector as the src for an `ImageView`, `enabled="false"` is being ignored.

i.e. this doesn't work properly:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:src="@drawable/state_drawable" >
```

P.S. :
*I have an ugly workaround, I'll post it as an answer shortly, if you have something better or an explanation for this behavior, please let me know.*

Comment: What is your workaround? The accepted solution didn't work for me

Comment: @ThanosFisherman see my answer below, starts with "Possible workaround"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to add the property android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 2):

Possible workaround: use a `TextView` with a compound drawable:

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/state_drawable"
     android:enabled="false" />
```

This seems to work, and pull the right drawable from state_drawable, but not very intuitive.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have just add the property of:

```
android:background="@drawable/image_selector"
```

and the "android:src" is not necessary to be added.

Now in your example it should look like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/state_drawable" >
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

For me worked only this:

```
image.setClickable(false);
```

For ImegeView android:enabled="false" for some reason doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension function to enable/disable an ImageView/ImageButton without selector

```
fun ImageView.setImageViewEnabled(enabled: Boolean) = if(enabled) {
    drawable.clearColorFilter()
    isEnabled = true
} else {
    drawable.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    isEnabled = false
}
```